# Confused about $.ajax() when traditional and async are false

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have the following code:

```
var params = {
  task: task,
  pk: pk,
  rk: rk,
  responses: null
}

var resp = [];
$(".city-checkbox").each(function () {
  var i = parseInt(this.id.match(/\d+/)[0], 10);
  resp[i] = this.checked;
});
parms.responses = resp;

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  traditional: true,
  async: false,
  data: parms,
  dataType: "json",

  [...]
});
```

My code sends a POST request to a ASP MVC action. I looked at the jQuery documentation but still cannot understand what traditional does. Can someone explain if I really need to use this here.

Same with async false: Is there any disadvantage to it?

Comment: async false results in the browser pausing until the request is complete, usually resulting in a bad user experience on non-localhost networks.

Comment: traditional: true stops jQuery from doing a deep serialization of your data. For example, if your params contained an array, traditional:true would prevent jQuery from handling it the way modern frameworks expect it to be handled.

Comment: My params does contain an array.

Comment: Then you may want to remove traditional:true if you run into problems getting your data on the server-side.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation for `traditional` is actually over at [jQuery.param](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/):

> As of jQuery 1.4, the `$.param()` method serializes deep objects recursively to accommodate modern scripting languages and frameworks such as PHP and Ruby on Rails. You can disable this functionality globally by setting `jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;`.

Whether or not you want to use the flag depends upon how your backend is going to deserialize the parameters. Unless you are running into trouble you probably want to stick with the default value of `false` - but I could be wrong. You should test it out in your particular environment.

---

Update - As Kevin says, unless you really know what you are doing, you should *never* use `async: false` because it will block the user's browser until the AJAX call completes. You will have no control over this. A better approach is to go with the default `async: true` and display a spinning GIF or such to block the UI yourself and let the user know they need to wait.

Comment: You should never use async: false? I think this statement is totally wrong and misleading. It depends on the situation!

Comment: @WolleVanillebärLutz - I stand by my answer, though I do concede that `async` is there for a reason. It can save development time, at the expense of risking a poor user experience if the back-end blocks for a noticeable amount of time. If you are on a high-speed local network then *maybe* you could get away with it, but that is a very specific case...

Comment: That's your opinion. But you can't generalize this statement to each situation. For example in game-developing, it could be important to synchronize your serverrequests... It's also important to state out that javascript runs in a single execution thread, don't forget that!

Comment: @WolleVanillebärLutz - Right, JS runs in a single thread, which is why it is important not to block that thread. 'async: false' can block it for an arbitrary amount of time. Your JS game would appear to freeze if a call took (EG) a second to complete. You can chain your requests instead to guarantee order, for example.

Comment: Please tell me, why do you think it is implemented, if it's totally bad practice? Opinions can't be wrong... What if you want the page to freeze? What if you don't want your site to react on user input, while you show a loader-animation? ...

Comment: @WolleVanillebärLutz - There is a good discussion of this over here: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11013 - perhaps it is overkill to say you should *never* use sync calls, since there seem to be a couple of edge cases that require it. But in the general case you do not want to use sync ajax calls.

Comment: That's what i said ;)